# Disable Air-tap based button click on Holo Lens 2 (using Unity for development)

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I am trying to disable only the air-tap on my buttons, while still keeping the GGV (Gaze/Gesture/Voice) pointer enabled. I am seeing ways to completely disable far interactions; but I want to retain far interactions (GGV pointer).

Comment: May I ask what is the scenario? Air Tap is not just for far interaction. If what you want is to turn off the hand ray, then you can refer to [Pointers - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/pointers?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) to delete or turn off unneeded pointers. You can also refer to **Mixed Reality Toolkit Examples->Demos-Input->DisablePointers** to enable or disable pointers by code.

Comment: We noticed that our users accidentally were air-tapping on buttons (we have several buttons on screen). So we wanted to turn it off based on user feedback. We want the hand ray enabled for activating a button by pointing at it and using a voice command. We also want to keep the pointer enabled. If there is a way to only block the air tap (pinch) gesture for selecting buttons...

Comment: hi @AparajithSairam are you using MRTK for this? Select, in some cases, maps to the pinch/airtap gesture.

Comment: Yes, I am using MRTK. Can you please elaborate on your idea?

Comment: thanks @AparajithSairam . can you share MRTK & Unity versions?

Comment: Sure. Unity 2021.3.8f1 and MRTK 2.8.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to disable Air-Tap. But for your requirements, you can try to use the **SpeechInputHandler** component instead of the **Interactable** component on those buttons that are easy to accidentally touch. Please refer to [Speech - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/speech?view=mrtkunity-2022-05#handling-speech-input).

Comment: Ended up disabling hand-ray